# Help with asp.net mvc https

Tags: asp.net-mvc, https

I have my HomeController decorated with [RequireHttps], the problem is that my certificate is just on http://www.mysite.com

Now, if people go to http://mysite.com they get an Untrusted Connection error (on Firefox)

What can I do to prvent this from happening?

Answer (score 4):

My simple solution would be to have a requirement that all mysite.com are redirected to www.mysite.com. Is better for SEO as well I think.

This can be set in IIS.